# Value of type <anonymous type> cannot be converted to <anonymous type>

Tags: vb.net, linq, anonymous-types

I am sure i am doing something terribly wrong, but i should better ask the experts.

At the third line i get the error `Value of type <anonymous type> cannot be converted to <anonymous type>`

```
Dim Query = (From c In Db.web Select New With {.AA = c.AA}).ToList
Dim v = New With {.Amount = 108}
Query.Add(v)
```

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have named your fields differently (and maybe it has different type as well, I don't know, cause I don't know what type `c.AA` is), compiler has created different type for `v`, so you have 2 anonymous classes, with different fields (even if they have same type, but their name differs) and they are not compatible with each other.

I don't know VB.Net well, but something like this:

```
Dim Query = (From c In Db.web Select New With {.Amount = CInt(c.AA)}).ToList
Dim v = New With {.Amount = 108}
Query.Add(v)
```

Should solve the problem, at least works in `C#`.

Answer (score 1):

Anonymous type identity is based not just on the *types* of the members, but on their *names* as well. So these two objects are of different types, even though to human eyes they have the 'same' structure:

```
Dim a = New With { .Name = "Bob" }
Dim b = New With { .Moniker = "Robert" }
```

So even if `c.AA` is an `Integer`, that's not enough for `Query` and `v` to be type-compatible.

Obviously your code is distilled from your real problem, so I can't say exactly what you should be doing instead, but perhaps using a named rather than an anonymous type will solve your problem.

This is documented in the VB.NET Spec (from eg version 9.0 [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=995)), section 11.10.4 "Anonymous Object-Creation Expressions" (my emphases) :

> If two anonymous class creation expressions occur within the same
>   method and yield the same resulting shape—**if the property order,
>   property names, and property types all match**—they will both refer to
>   the same anonymous class.
>
> Annotation
>
> **It is possible that a compiler may choose to unify anonymous types further, such as at the assembly level, but this  cannot be relied upon at this time.**

By contrast to the annotation, I believe that for *C#*, the compiler *does* guarantee anonymous type identity across an assembly when everything matches.